# Single quotation mark in select on vb.net and the dataset is from reading xml file

Tags: vb.net

Hi I need to get the rows for user input. I cannot get the data with the input has single quotation mark in select. The dataset is read by xml file.  There has data for the following example
There is my code

```
'The ds is return by reading xml file:  
Dim sw As New StringWriter
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.ReadXml(strXMLFilePath)

Dim total As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
Dim rows As DataRow() = New DataRow(total) {}
Dim sortOrder As String = "FileName ASC"
'Dim strGroup as string="Pop" (worked- has rows)
Dim strGroup as string="Uncle's brand" (no rows)

  rows = ds.Tables(0).Select("Category='" & strGroup & "'", sortOrder)
```

Comment: You need to escape it `"Uncle''s brand"`

Comment: @Plutonix I tried your suggestion, it didn't return the row

Answer (score 0):

Try using two single quotes. In other words, change the strGroups into this:

```
Dim strGroup as string="Uncle''s brand"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but no row return